# How to get current runing process number of current user?

Tags: c++, linux, process

I need to find out the current runing process number of current user in a c++ program, how can I do this?
Working os is Centos8

Answer (score 1):

As your question is tagged `linux` so my answer is only valid for linux based operating systems and [POSIX-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems) systems.

`unistd.h` is a part of POSIX environment.

> The <unistd.h> header defines miscellaneous symbolic constants
> and types, and declares miscellaneous functions.

Read more about [`unistd.h`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/unistd.h.0p.html). I'm using a function called [`getpid()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/getpid.html), which returns the [process ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier#Unix-like) of the current instance of the program which is being executed on the kernel.

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h> // getpid() function
#include <iostream> // std::cout and std::endl

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Process ID: " << getpid() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works on many POSIX-compliant systems other than just Linux.

Comment: But you also said “my answer is only valid for Linux-based operating systems”.